# Dictionary sorting and removing

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I'm stuck on dictionaries and sorting in python, I have the following values stored in a dictionary:

```
{'PersonA': 87.0, 'PersonB': 89.0, 'PersonC': 101, 'PersonD': 94, 'PersonE': 112}
```

I want to:

1) Sort these so that they are ordered by highest score first, to lowest score 
2) Remove the scores from the dictionary, leaving only the names

E.g in the example above the function should return:

```
['PersonE', 'PersonC', 'PersonD', 'PersonB', 'PersonA']
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do this easily with [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
>>> d = {'PersonA': 87.0, 'PersonB': 89.0, 'PersonC': 101, 'PersonD': 94, 'PersonE': 112}
>>> sorted(d, key=d.get, reverse=True)
['PersonE', 'PersonC', 'PersonD', 'PersonB', 'PersonA']
>>>
```

Note that the output is a list of names though.  You cannot sort a dictionary or a set in Python because they are both naturally unordered.

Comment: Nice to know, didn't know you could sort a dictionary!

Comment: @ReutSharabani - You can't sort a dictionary.  This is just iterating over the dictionary's keys and collecting them into a sorted list, using `dict.get` to determine the order.

Comment: I know, I meant using `sorted` directly on the dictionary keys. On the other hand you can iterate over them just like a `list` or a `tuple`, so why not...

Answer (score 2):

You can do as follows:

```
d1 = {'PersonA': 87.0, 'PersonB': 89.0, 'PersonC': 101, 'PersonD': 94, 'PersonE': 112}
print([n for n,s in sorted(d1.items(), key=lambda v:v[1], reverse=True)])
```

Which results in:

```
['PersonE', 'PersonC', 'PersonD', 'PersonB', 'PersonA']
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to sort a dictionary , because dictionary is orderless, but other types, such as lists and tuples, are not.But you can have a sorted representation.

For instance,

```
import operator
x = {first: 2, second: 4, third:3, fourth:1, fifth:0}
sorted_x = sorted(x.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

or you can also do

```
sorted(x.values()) to get a sorted representation.
```

Answer (score 0):

An option to keep the dic and sort it:

```
>>>from collections import OrderedDict

>>> # regular unsorted dictionary
>>> d = {'banana': 3, 'apple':4, 'pear': 1, 'orange': 2}

>>> # dictionary sorted by key
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
OrderedDict([('apple', 4), ('banana', 3), ('orange', 2), ('pear', 1)])

>>> # dictionary sorted by value
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[1]))
OrderedDict([('pear', 1), ('orange', 2), ('banana', 3), ('apple', 4)])

>>> # dictionary sorted by length of the key string
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: len(t[0])))
OrderedDict([('pear', 1), ('apple', 4), ('orange', 2), ('banana', 3)])
```

Detail: sorted has the reverse(bool) arg, ex:

```
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[0], reverse = True))
OrderedDict([('pear', 1), ('orange', 2), ('banana', 3), ('apple', 4)])
```

The usage is normal:

```
>>> dic = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
>>> dic['banana']
3
```

font: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes